# Findings common paths in two graphs using python-networkx

Tags: path, generator, networkx

I have two DiGraphs, say G and H, and I would like to count how many paths of G are part of H.

For any node pairs (src, dst) I can generate the paths between them using the 'all_simple_paths' function to get the generators:
G_gen = nx.all_simple_paths(G, src, dst)
H_gen = nx.all_simple_paths(H, src, dst)

Since the amount of paths is considerably high (the graphs have typically 100 nodes) I cannot resort to building lists etc.. (e.g. list(G_gen)) so I am wondering if there are smarter ways to deal with it. In addition, I would also like to distinguish based on the path lengths.

.. or maybe a better solution can be found with a different module ?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is some reason why `nx.intersection` ([see here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.intersection.html)) wouldn't work here? I'm not sure if it checks for direction under the hood but it doesn't seem to force outputs to standard `Graph` output either. Below might work:

```py
# Create a couple of random preferential attachment graphs
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100, 5)
H = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100, 5)

# Convert to directed
G = G.to_directed()
H = H.to_directed()

# Get intersection
intersection = nx.intersection(G, H)

# Print info for each
print(nx.info(G))
print(nx.info(H))
print(nx.info(intersection))
```

which outputs:

```py
>>> DiGraph with 100 nodes and 950 edges
>>> DiGraph with 100 nodes and 950 edges
>>> DiGraph with 100 nodes and 176 edges
```

The nodes are all shared in the example since the node ids are just simple integers and so they follow the same generation index. With real data I suppose your node sets might not be equivalent like here and you probably will see differences there too.

On the path lengths I'm not quite sure how you would go about that. The intersection just checks which nodes and edges are shared between two graphs and returns those that are in both, unaware of any other conditions I suspect. There might be a way to impose some additional constraints by adapting the source code with of the intersection function with some conditional checks.

**I guess this doesn't check the number of *paths* but rather the number of *edges*, so I suppose you're looking for something more specific than this.** But at the very least no path can exist outside of the intersection, since all shared paths must contain the same edges in both (since if an edge is missing from a path in either, it cannot exist as a path in the shared solution).

Hope this helps in some way shape or form, though I feel I've oversimplified your question quite a bit.

EDIT: Intuitively, the full solution to your question might be to simply enumerate all possible paths in the intersection.